# Karate API - Basic Auth in scenario could not override Bearer token created in karate-config.json

Tags: api, karate

I use bearer token for all my tests created in karate-config.js file. However for certain negative scenarios, I need to validate the error message for unauthorized users.

To achieve this, I created a basic auth header authorization inside scenario file. However it does not seem to override the bearer token. Please help

[image: NegativeScenario]

Response is still picking up Bearer token

[image: Response]

My config.js file

[image: config.js]

Tried callonce and call but in vain

Comment: This is Awesome @peter-thomas Really appreciate your timely response.